# Is it possible to customize invitation email?

Tags: osx-server, customization, profile-manager

I'm a newbie with OS X Server and specially with Profile Manager.

I have already managed to make enrollment work, but I'm wondering if it is possible to **change the template** of the invitation email since it is pretty awful and leaves no space for branding or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your HD > Applications > Server.app

Right Click > Show Package Contents

Go to Contents > ServerRoot > usr > share > devicemgr > backend > app > views > emailer

Open the email_profile-multipart.erb file in your IDE of choice, and make your style edits to the HTML email.